# How to use Angular inside of Asp.Net MVC views?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular

I have HTML pages with server rendered content. 
Now I'm using Angular 1.5 and all pages have `ng-app` and angular directives are  seeded in markup. So my app is not no single page application, it uses angular directives for widgets, and UI controls. For example:

```
@model PageViewModel
 <html ng-app="app"> 
 ...
 <body>
    <form> 
      <input type="text" name="@Html.NameFor(x => x.Name)"/>

      <file-upload name="@Html.NameFor(x => x.Logo)" value="@Html.ValueFor(x => x.Logo)"></file-upload>
      <file-upload name="@Html.NameFor(x => x.Teaser)" value="@Html.ValueFor(x => x.Teaser)"></file-upload>

      <input type="submit"/>   
    </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

I want to migrate views to Angular 4, but it looks very focused on single page application with one root component.
How can I do same code on Angular 4?
Should I place all page content inside of angular root element or something else?

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
@model PageViewModel
 <html> 
 ...
 <body>
 <app-root> 
    <form> 
      <input type="text" name="@Html.NameFor(x => x.Name)"/>

      <file-upload name="@Html.NameFor(x => x.Logo)" value="@Html.ValueFor(x => x.Logo)"></file-upload>
      <file-upload name="@Html.NameFor(x => x.Teaser)" value="@Html.ValueFor(x => x.Teaser)"></file-upload>

      <input type="submit"/>   
    </form>
 </app-root>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Take a look at this repo: https://github.com/mithunvp/ng2Mvc5Demo

Comment: @lbrahim question is how to place server generated code inside of <my-app>Loading...</my-app>

Answer (score 1):

a more simple way, if you can handle having 1 component per page, is to render the js files and copy them to a folder and just call `<app-root>`

i have an example playing with the idea http://bresleveloper.blogspot.co.il/2017/09/angular-4-with-net-webformsmvc-tutorial.html

for a more heavily integrated solution http://www.mithunvp.com/using-angular-2-asp-net-mvc-5-visual-studio/